# Getting NULL when calling recursive method using BigIntegers and memoization

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger, memoization

I got the method working using the long data type, but when I go to call my BigInteger recursive method, it says "null" when I println it.
Here is my long recursive method that works for me:

```
public static long fib_rec(int n){
    long result=1;
    if(n<=2){
        return result;
    }
    else{
        if(fval[n]!=0){
            result=fval[n];
        }
        else{
            result = fib_rec(n-1) + fib_rec(n-2);
            fval[n] = result;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Again, that method works perfectly until I go past n = 94, where the values are too large for the long data type.
Here is my BigInteger attempt, full program:

```
public class BigInt {

    static BigInteger[] fval;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int index;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        index = input.nextInt();

        fval = new BigInteger[index + 1];


        System.out.println(fib_rec(index));
    }

    public static BigInteger fib_rec(int index){

        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

        if(index <= 2){
            return result;
        }

        else{
            if(fval[index] != BigInteger.ZERO){
                result=fval[index];
            }
            else{
                 result = fib_rec(index-1).add(fib_rec(index-2));

                fval[index] = result;

            }
            return result;
        }
    }  
  }
```

This returns null and I have no idea why...

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming a BigInteger array starts filled with zeros like a long array, but it starts full of nulls instead, as it is an an object array, so this:

```
if(fval[index] != BigInteger.ZERO){
    result=fval[index];
}
```

will always return null, as the `null` values do not equal `BigInteger.ZERO`.

If you add this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < index+1; i++) {
  fval[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
}
```

before your call to `fib_rec` then it works.